# Locate a resized subimage inside an image

Tags: c#, image-processing, emgucv

I am working in a project where each user has a big avatar and a thumbnail of this avatar. The avatar is 150x215 and the thumbnail is 50x50. To generate the thumbnail, the user selects a square area inside the avatar and the system crops and resizes the avatar to generate the thumbnail.

Now I need to have a 70x70 thumbnail. I cannot resize the 50x50 thumbnail because it does not look nice. My idea was to create a tool to find the thumbnail inside the avatar and, using the thumbnail location, generate the new 70x70 image. It was working well until I notice that some thumbnails are not only cropped, they are resized. When the image is resized it loses pixels what makes a pixel-by-pixel comparison impossible (so I can't detect the thumbnail location inside the avatar).

Is there any way to identify where the thumbnail is located(even though it is resized)? I am using [EMGU](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) to handle the images.

Thanks for any help

Comment: I guess you didn't store the coordinates that the use chose in the first place?

Comment: Yes, you are right. The location is not stored. The idea of comparing the thumbnail to the avatar was to get this location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[EDIT1]**

Seeing your note, if you had the scaling factors applied to the original avatar, then you could create a temp thumbnail that has the same scaling factor applied, then perform a statistical equivalence check of the thumbnail against the already scaled avatar.  What this would look like is finding the "difference image" of the thumbnail against the scaled avatar image for each location the thumbnail can possibly lie within the avatar.  for each of these "difference images" add all of the pixel based differences into a combined single numeric difference and store that into a 2D array sized to the dimension of x and y locations the thumbnail can possibly be placed within the scaled avatar image (this will be smaller than the total avatar image size, infact it will be width = avatarWidth - thumbWidth and height = avatarHeight - thumbHeight).  After you have calculated all of the single difference instances for this 2D array, simply find the min within the array and that is the top-left pixel location within the scaled avatar to use.  You will of course have to take the new scaled size of the 50 x 50 thumb into account when grabbing your 70 x 70 from this calculated top-left point.

You dont (by the way) have to store this 2D array of difference values,  You could simply hold a min location that is initialized with the value from the first tested location, and only update if the current location is less than the current min.  This would avoid the added storage of the array.

**[ORIGINAL]**
Once the avatar image has been resized, it has also been interpolated, which for all intensive purposes means that the original pixel information has been mathmatically changed irreversibly.

You may have better luck getting into the original thumbnailing code, and changing the thumbnail code to grab the 70 x 70 px sub-image, then create the 50 x 50 by cropping another 10 px from each side!!!  This is assuming you still need both the 50 x50 and the 70 x 70 thumbnails.

Comment: Yes, that is true and good for the new users, but I need to handle the older user's avatars :(

Comment: Check out the edit!!!  Remember with this method though, you will "most likely" never get to a difference value of zero so dont necessarily expect it.  You may also have to do some checking of negative difference values.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately I do not have: if the user selects a 20x20 area, it is resized to 50x50. If the user selects a 100x100 area, it is also resized to a 50x50. That happens to any size of area, so I don't even know if the image was resized to get bigger or smaller than the selected area :(
I am starting to think that this is not feasible in the time frame I have :(
thanks anyway :)

Comment: Without more meta data to accompany your images, this may even be an all but impossible task!!!  You are (without it) talking about trying to auto-correlate size and position of 2 images where 1 or both images' size may have changed!

Comment: yes, it looks like that :(
thanks for the clarification anyway :)
Marking as answer due to this comments discussion

Comment: Sorry that there isnt a "better" answer for your dilemna :-)